# trying to put another span onder the span

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put another span underneath the first span but also on the the same line as the circle.

https://jsfiddle.net/rmje7xz3/10/

This is the html

```
 <div class="dialog-box">
    <div class="dialog-box-circle"></div>
    <span class="dialog-box-name">My Name -
      <select>
        <option>@private</option>       
        <option>@public</option>        
      </select>
    </span>
    <span class="dialog-box-day">theproblem<span>
    <span class="dialog-box-text">Dont forget to bring the new calender for the meeting.</span>
 </div>
```

this is the css

```
.container{
    position:absolute;
    width:382px;
    height:529px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:#cccccc;
}
header{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:41px;
    color:white;
    background-color:#de4b4b;   
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:14px;
    margin:auto;


}
header span{
display:inline-block;
padding-left:172px;
padding-top:14px;
padding-bottom:14px;

}
.sub-header{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:37px;
    background-color:white;
    font-size:10px;
    margin:auto;
    color:black;


}
.sub-header span{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-top:14px;
    padding-left:10px;
}
.dialog-box{
    position:absolute;
    width:365px;    
    background-color:white;

    margin: 10px 8px 10px 8px;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
}
.dialog-box-circle{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
    border-radius:30px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    margin:15px 10px 17px 15px;
    vertical-align:middle;

}
.dialog-box-name{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#6495ED;
    font-size:12px;

}
.dialog-box-text{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#cccccc;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:'roboto_light';
    margin-left:15px;

}
.dialog-box-name select {
        border:0px;
        font-size:10px;
        font-family:'roboto_light';
        color:#454545;

}
.dialog-box-name select option{

}
.dialog-box-day{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:9px;
    font-family:'roboto_light';
    }

ul{
        display:inline-block;
        list-style: none;

    }
```

there is a link on the top of the page to make life easier for every one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all you need to do is float `.dialog-box-circle`. Set it to `float:left;` and you should see what you're looking for.

I am not a fan of floats, but with images and in a box-model like this, it should do no harm.

Comment: OK now its floats but  how do i free the space under the circle ??

Comment: If you want text to sit underneath that circle, it looks like you just need to adjust the `margin-bottom` property to less than 13px. I set margin as `.dialog-box-circle{margin:15px 10px 10px 15px;}` and it looks good.

Answer (score 3):

you are missing one closing span tag

```
<span class="dialog-box-day">theproblem<span>
            <span class="dialog-box-text">Dont forget to bring the new calender for the meeting.</span>
```

3 opening spans and one closing